# How to extract 7zip archives with relative paths

Tags: 7zip

I have an archive myfile.7z that contains the single file

```
\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\myfile.txt
```

When I open this archive in 7-zip gui, navigate to Folder3, click it and click the "Extract" icon, it will correctly extract the relative path:

```
\Folder3\Folder4\myfile.txt
```

However when I run the following from command line to extract Folder3:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x myfile.7z -r Folder1\Folder2\Folder3
```

Instead of extracting the relative path starting with Folder3 in the same fashion as the gui, it extracts the full path:

```
\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\myfile.txt
```

How do I get the command line version to extract relative paths the same way the gui does?